# Do puzzles need to be original?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm new to this site and really like it so far. I've read all the [help](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/) documents and am unclear on whether puzzles need to be original in order to be posted. All the original content on this site is extremely impressive and I think it will be a while until I can create questions as polished as the ones here (definitely something to aspire to though).

That said, I have long been a huge fan of logic puzzles and know dozens of them by heart. None of them are my own creation, but I still think the community might enjoy them.

I am wondering if it is appropriate for me to post these puzzles as long as they are not already posted on the site?

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. I decided to accept the answer from Anachor because I think other new users that might come across this post should be warned to thoroughly check for duplicates when posting non-original puzzles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kingrames already said the puzzles need not be original. However, if you are posting a previously known puzzle, do make sure it is not a duplicate. On other SE sites checking for duplicates is a trivial task, but because of the nature of puzzling, it is somewhat harder here.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, go for it. Just be sure to mention you didn't invent the thing.